# Play Framework 2: Printable Documentation

Tags: printing, playframework, playframework-2.0

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717168/play-framework-2-downloadable-documentation) is asking for a downloadable documentation in general, I'm currently trying to find a good way to print the official Play framework documentation. My problem is that the whole documentation (available online) is split into small chunks of information and printing the whole documentation would mean hundreds of print jobs, each wasting a significant amount of paper. Is there some way to convert the whole documentation in a single/compact printable format? This would make a nice holiday reading :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently PDF documentation disappeared since Play version 2.1.0, I can see that is still available in 2.0.x if this satisfies you...

Anything I can advice is making a static copy of the pages so you can read it with some smartphone or tablet.

Comment: If @bluenote10 wants to take it for holiday reading he also can print MEAP (http://www.manning.com/leroux/) but it costs $39.99.

Comment: No possibilities for smartphone/tablet reading in my case, so I really need a version on paper. I first downloaded `play-2.0.8.zip`, which also lacks a PDF documentation. Then I tried `play-2.0.zip`, and this version indeed contains a PDF! The fact that it's not for the most recent Play version is not an issue for me. Though in general it would be great if the most recent versions would ship with a printable version as well, maybe even with improvements like introducing a structured numbering and less waste of white space.